# What are the differences between a basic configuration and a full configuration of a network device?

Tags: switch, router, networking, netconf

When someone is talking about a basic/base configuration of a network device, does this mean the startup configuration file? And when a full configuration is referenced how is it different from a basic configuration file? You might know that I a newbie in this field already. But your inputs might help severals like me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic or base configuration is typically referred to, as the minimal configuration needed for your network device to function.

A full configuration is typically the basic/base configuration plus all the extra security features, management configurations and other features that you can add to your network device.

Comment: Does ZTP config mean base configuration then? Can this be included inside full configuration? Thanks Cown.

Comment: What is ZTP config?

Comment: zero touch provisioning, in terms of automating a network device.

Comment: The Switch auto install feature is enabled by default, when you turn it on for the first time.